# What decisions can a player make when performing a compelled attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, attack, conditions

Say a character is under the influence of the [confusion](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Confusion#content) spell and they roll a 7 or an 8 to determine their action. So they try to attack an adjacent character. Now say the character has at least 2 levels of [barbarian](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Barbarian#content) so their have the option to perform a reckless attack. Do they have that option available to them under those circumstances? What if the character is wielding a finesse weapon, do they have the option of choosing between strength and dexterity for the attack and damage rolls? What if the character is wielding a two-handed weapon and has the great weapon fighting class feature? Can they choose whether they reroll any damage dice if they hit?

Comment: I don't think it is because Crown of Madness does not reference the spell Confusion and uses (albeit slightly) different language.

Comment: The core of that other question is about whether you could do something like make an unarmed attack instead of whatever weapon you have in your hands.

Comment: Close vote removed. Related: "[When affected by the Crown of Madness spell, can I choose what type of melee attack to make?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/154281)"

Answer (score 1):

### Spells do what they say they do

> The creature uses its action to make a melee attack ...

They must make a “melee attack”; the spell requires nothing else. Therefore the details are up to the character - if they are targeting a friend they can make an unarmed strike to minimize damage, if they are targeting an enemy they can go all out.

Comment: Where's the fun in that? :D Smite your friends!