# Can you use Booming Blade with Sentinel's reaction attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, cantrips

The description of the feat Sentinel says:

> When a creature within 5 feet of you makes an attack against a target other than you (and that target doesn't have this feat), **you can use your reaction to make a melee weapon attack against the attacking creature.**

Now I'm wondering, could I potentially use this with Booming Blade since the spell implies the use of a melee weapon attack? I'm unsure if this would count as casting a spell or making a melee weapon attack.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I use a spell to make an Opportunity Attack?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/108796/can-i-use-a-spell-to-make-an-opportunity-attack) It's for opportunity attacks rather than reactions, but the timing rationale is the same (spell as a reaction without Warcaster).

Comment: It should be noted that by RAW, you cannot use a spell for a Sentinel OA even if you also have War Caster, because War Caster specifically states it triggers when an enemy's *movement* grants you an OA, and Sentinel's OA is triggered by the enemy's attack, not their movement.